# What is not a row in a csv file?

Tags: python, row, load-csv

I came upon this code in a tutorial:

```
 for row in csv_reader:
        if not row:
            continue
        dataset.append(row)
```

Which I take to mean that if the code encounters something other than a row, just skip and continue. Is that correct?

What defines 'not row'?

Comment: An empty line. Maybe you have a blank line and you want to ignore it. This would give you all non-empty lines.

Comment: not negates whatever is passed to it. not True is False.

Comment: It's checking to see of the "truthiness" of `row` is `False` which would indicate the value returned was an empty sequence of elements.

Comment: I thought it might be an empty row among other things, but I can't seem to find definitive literature. @ martineau, you sound pretty definitive so I'll go with that until something reveals that it is not. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Truthy and Falsy in python? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: @ Merik, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows you to skip over empty lines in a CSV file.

---

`not row` just means "`row` is falsey".

In Python, the following things are falsey:

- `False`
- `None`
- Numeric zeroes
- Empty containers

(Of course you can write your own class with a `__bool__` method that does anything you want—but by convention, it should follow the same rule.)

This is all explained in [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) in the docs.

--

The rows iterated by a `csv.reader` are lists. (And lists are containers, so they're falsey iff they're empty.)

An empty line produces an empty list; a line with text but no delimiters produces a list of one string; a line with delimiters produces a list of two or more strings.

This is covered in the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module docs… but not really all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

`row` is just a variable name in this context. When you do `if row`, you actually checking if there is any content to the variable that python considers to be `True`.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/2535611) from Patrick Haugh in which he highlights lots of examples of what is `Falsy` in python.

To illustrate in a minimal example:

```
import csv
for row in csv.reader(['row1,foo','', 'row3,bar']):
    print(row)
```

yields

```
['row1', 'foo']
[]
['row3', 'bar']
```

But if you do

```
for row in csv.reader(['row1,foo','', 'row3,bar']):
    if row:
        print(row)
```

Then output is

```
['row1', 'foo']
['row3', 'bar']
```

and thus basically the empty row is filtered out.

Comment: Surely you wanted to use the same list in your second example as in your first? Because that will just print out the line `['one', 'two', 'three', '']`.

Comment: Perhaps it is more efficient to write: for row in csv_reader:
                                                               if row:
                                                               dataset.append(row)